# How do sync programs get around the iOS sandbox?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, permission, sandbox

The various iOS sync programs ([SugarSync](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sugarsync/id288491637?mt=8), BitTorrent Sync, etc.) claim to be able to read files anywhere on the phone. I don't see how data from my application -- in my app's sandbox -- can be accessed. How is it that these programs are able to read/write outside their sandbox and get my app's data?

Comment: What data are we talking about? Here is the [developers guide for storage](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/). With iOS 8 people will be able to sync using dropbox, one drive, or google drive instead of iCloud drive. But only the ones that are in the "syncable" in the application directory.

Comment: I think I didn't quiet understand your question. Is SugarSync or BitTorrent Sync a program on iPhone or PC/Mac, because on PC/Mac they can. I have the free iFunBox (i wanted to know what it can do), and with that I can access anything on my iPhone. All the app data, user data etc.

Answer (score 8):

**They can't** as all 3rd-party apps on a non-jailbroken iOS device are limited by the sandbox, both installed from the App Store and from ad-hoc/enterprise distribution.

Either they are using public APIs to access data 'the iOS way' (structured and anticipated) such as accessing the Camera Roll to import/save photos, or are integrated with an app to share data in a way that the developers of *both* apps have worked together to make it happen (this doesn't necessarily mean they actually know each other as they could have used a framework, such as the Dropbox framework).